# Is it possible to use a third-party unauthorized charger with an iPad running iOS 7

Tags: charging, ios, charger

Is it possible to use a third-party unauthorized charger with an iPad running iOS 7? I have an iPad 2 with a 30 pin connector.

Comment: Do you get the warning ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the charger supplies the correct wattage, the version of iOS shouldn't matter.

Comment: This is not always true. Software changes can change how fussy the device is about getting precisely the right wattage. Apple also performs other checks sometimes.